# call python method in parallel from a loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a method 1 in which loop is running and calling another method 2 
but i want to know that how i can call method 2 in parallel as it is performing some sequential steps and call-1 of method 2 should be seprate from call-2 of method 2 ... so on here is my code
Method 2

```
def upload_image(img):
    sess = requests.Session()
    sess.verify = False
    start_upload_response = requests.post('https://awsimgproc.com/start_upload', data={"album_id36": 1}, verify=False)
    start_upload_response.raise_for_status()
    result = start_upload_response.json()
    our_upload = result['upload_id36']
    url = 'https://awsimgproc.com/uploadImage'
    files = {'file': open(img, 'rb')}
    data = {'upload_id36':our_upload}
    # This makes the post requests async
    global api_response
    api_response.append(grequests.post(url,data=data,files=files))
```

Method 1

```
def image_generator():
    # Change here the location of iamge file
    image_file_location = "/home/gaurav/Pictures/sofa-3"
    extension = ".jpg"
    i=1
    img = Image.open(image_file_location + extension)

    start_time = datetime.now()

    # can change minutes as per need i.e for how much you need run 
    test suite
    end_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=1)

    while start_time < end_time:
        # change current image and randomly roating the image
        rotated_image = img.rotate(random.randint(1,1000))
        new_image_loaction = image_file_location+str(i)+extension
        rotated_image.save(new_image_loaction)

        # upload the newly rotated image
        upload_image(new_image_loaction)

        # uncomment this line to add sleep to your method
        # time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
        start_time = datetime.now()
        i += 1
```

Comment: Could you fix code formatting in the second code example? The indentation doesn't look right.

Comment: Okay I am doing it right

Comment: does replacing upload_image() call with multiprocessing.Process(target=upload_image, args=(new_image_loaction,)).start() will serve my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested in your own comment, multiprocessing is indeed one valid way of doing the upload asynchronously.

If you're interested to dive into more modern async programming in Python, your question is a good and simple use case to try out asyncio or one of the other asynchronous event loop implementations. See e.g. [awesome-asyncio](https://github.com/timofurrer/awesome-asyncio) for resources.